# Add a third-party module (angular2-signaturepad) without app.module.ts (Angular 2 / Ionic 2)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, signaturepad

I'm having some trouble with using a third-party module called *angular2-signaturepad.* Using this [guide](https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/)

The guide states that in order to use this module, you have to add *SignaturePadModule* to the *imports* section of *app.module.ts.* However, our project (using Ionic 2) does not have or use an *app.module.ts* file. All of our dependencies live in our *app.ts*, specifically our *ionicBootstrap* function

Since we don't have the *app.module.ts* file, I decided to add the *SignaturePadModule* to *app.ts*

`ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  DataService,
  UploadService,
  StorageService,
  ConnectionService,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ActionSheetController,
  AlertController,
  Device,
  Diagnostic,
  LoggingService,
  SettingsService,
  SnaggingService,
  **SignaturePadModule**,
  provide('Storage', { useClass: Storage })]
);`

I've created a new *ts* and *template* files for my page to display the module:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController, ToastController, PopoverController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Toast, Camera, DatePicker } from 'ionic-native';

import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { SnaggingService } from '../../services/snagging.service';
import { StorageService } from '../../services/storage.service';

import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/test-signature/signatures.html',
})

export class SignaturesPage {

    signature = "";
    isDrawing = false;

    @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
    private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
        'minWidth': 5,
        'canvasWidth': 500,
        'canvasHeight': 300
    };

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    drawComplete() {
        this.isDrawing = false;
    }

    drawStart() {
        this.isDrawing = true;
    }`
```

And added the following onto the *template*

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
        Signatures
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  Please provide a signature please
  <signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>
  <canvas id="" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
</ion-content>
```

My app starts up and deploys to my device successfully, but when I browse to the page in question, no canvas or anything is displayed. I don't get any errors on Developer Tools and I can see the HTML for  again using Developer Tools, but I don't know how to overcome this issue

Any ideas here would be helpful, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue; the project I'm working in was originally created when Ionic 2 was still in beta, and as such, various components have moved on such as ionicBoostrap which is no longer used in the release candidate.

I resolved this by adding

`directives: [SignaturePad]`

to the Component decorator. After adding this one line and redeploying, I was able to draw on screen.